# Firestore query with filter causes memory leak in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I ran a leak profiler on Xcode to check my app memory status and found huge **leaks** coming out from my database services which I use Firestore for. I get that there are leaks from that code as provided in the screenshot.

[image: Xcode leaks instrument screenshot along]

```
    // MARK: - Private Properties

private lazy var database: Firestore = Firestore.firestore()
private lazy var usersCollectionReference = {
    return database.collection(MPRFirebaseUser.repoName)
}()

    // MARK: - Public  Functions

func fetchUser(withUserID userID: String, completion: @escaping (Result<MPRUserProtocol, Error>) -> Void) {
    let query = usersCollectionReference.whereField(MPRFirebaseUser.CodingKeys.id.rawValue, isEqualTo: userID)
    query.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let document = snapshot?.documents.first,
           let user: MPRFirebaseUser = MPRFirebaseHelper.getModel(fromDocument: document) {
            completion(.success(user))
        } else {
            completion(.failure(error ?? CustomError.with(localizedDescription: MPRLocalizationKeys.couldNotParseUserModelErrorMessage.text)))
        }
    }
}
```

I commented it out and returned the default result immediately without building and performing a query and the leak is **gone**, I have the same issue with any query that uses whereField.

Any idea? am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, edited. I apologize for that mistake.

Comment: Thank you, I've been checking this for quite good time now, I wish somebody answers unless it's a Firebase issue